# The size of MySQL and SQL Server databases

Tags: mysql, sql-server

When storing data in MySQL and storing the same data in SQL Server, will the size of the database differs or will it be the same for both?

**Updated:**  What I mean exactly if we have 20 GB of disk space, and we used both SQL Server and MySQL and stored the same data exactly for example, texts, dates. All data were the same exactly in both databaes, then will the size of both be the same?

Comment: What kind of data?  Text, numbers, dates?

Comment: Your update does not change my answer below.

Comment: @Donnie: ok will the difference between two be a big difference? 
I mean if I store 'Donnie' in MySQL and 'Donnie' in SQL Server, will 'Donnie' in SQL Server takes more size?

Comment: This couldn't be a less specific question.  You are basically asking "What would be bigger, this unspecified list of objects or this other unspecified list of objects?".  You have to have a known quantity on at least one side of the `=` to solve an equation.

Answer (score 5):

The size of the DB on disk is entirely implementation dependent, so it will likely be different.  If it's not, it's just a fluke.  It is also something that you shouldn't really worry about.  Just buy enough disk.

Comment: +1 - There's more to the data than the data...implementation of metadata I think will be a deciding factor in space.  Also indexes!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on many factors: block/page size, kind of data, kind of tables, type of indexes, recovery model (ms sql), data types and so on and so on.